# What could be causing my gas furnace to make a loud noise?

Tags: furnace, gas

I have  a comfort air natural gas furnace when it call for heat,their is a loud boom noise,could the hot surface ignitor have a crack or needs replacing?

Comment: Why do you suspect the ignitor?  Can you describe the noise a bit more, or upload a video to YouTube so we can hear it for ourselves.

Comment: What are your ducts made of? Solid metal (and possibly wrapped in insulation) or insulated flexible ducting?

Answer (score 1):

My gas furnace boomed like that until I took the cover off, brushed, vacuumed and blew out the burner box, then lightly wire brushed the ignitor electrodes.

A dirty burner box can cause booming.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty burner box can cause a loud noise when it starts because the gas is not traveling and mixing properly as it is released through the burner assembly.
As part of a service contract we would use a vacuum and a soft brush to vacuum the burner box out.

IF YOUR FURNACE HAS A HOT SURFACE IGNITOR YOU MUST BE VERY CAREFUL AROUND IT WHILE CLEANING THE BURNER BOX.

There was a couple of times that, due to neglect, the burner assembly was so dirty it had to be removed and washed.